# Unable to run php artisan migrate:refresh command in Php Storm Terminal

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, migration, database-migration

Unable to run the **`php artisan migrate:refresh`** & **`php artisan migrate`** command in the terminal.

I created the Migration File in the directory, and then deleted it manually from the sidebar rather than make it drop through Drop command. Now, I am unable to run the **migrate commands** plus the **raw sql queries**.

[image]

Anyone, who can help me out? Can I restore the file which I deleted?

Comment: Open phpmyadmin (or your preferred sql interface), look in the migrations table and delete the offending row

Comment: @Steve I have already deleted them from the **phpmyadmin**. Actually I created the migrated file to add specific columns into another migration file.

I ran this command ' 
  ' php artisan make:migration add_column --table="posts" '

Comment: You will need to post your migration, and please, do not post images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently deleted a migration called 'Add Column' and now migrate is searching for it, but can't find it. Delete this particular row manually in the migrations table in your database and the migrate should run.

Comment: I have already deleted the rows from the migration table in the database.

Comment: But did you delete the file too?

Comment: From the directory [C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\database\migrations]?

Comment: Yes. Migrate for some reason thinks it's there while it isn't

Comment: It automatically got deleted from the directory, too.

Comment: Then you probably need to add it again ;) You can also drop your database manually and migrate again if there is no data you need to keep

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121082/discussion-between-ahmed-qayyum-and-loek).